# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I'm getting an error from files in a tmp templates_c folder. The error in the error log looks like this:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in MYSITE/public_html/tmp/templates_c/%%62^625^625F77C9%%register.tpl.php on line 31
```

and the code on that line 31 is:

```
<?php 
$this->_block_content = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
echo smarty_block_m3_validate_box($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $this->_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat=false); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); 
?>
```

---

Here's the smarty_block_m3_validate_box function:

```
function smarty_block_m3_validate_box($params, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat)
{
    $required_params = array();

    $optional_params = array('form'=>'default'
                            ,'message'=> 'There was a problem:'
                            ,'class' => 'validation-box'
                            ,'assign' => ''
                            );

    // process parameters and bring into local namespace
    foreach($required_params as $p)
    {
        if (!isset($params[$p])) {
            $smarty->trigger_error("m3_validate_box: missing parameter: $p", E_USER_NOTICE);
            return '';
        }
        $$p = $params[$p];
    }

    foreach($optional_params as $parameter => $default_value)
    {
        $$parameter = empty($params[$parameter]) ? $default_value : $params[$parameter];
    }


    if (!empty($content)) 
    {
        // closing {{m3_validate_box}} tag
        if(!empty($_SESSION['SmartyValidate'][$form]['is_error']))
        {
            $output = "\n<div class='$class'>$message\n<ul>\n";
            $output .= $content;
            $output .= "\n</ul>\n</div>\n";

            if(!empty($assign))
                $smarty->assign($assign, $output);
            else
            {
                echo $output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have inherited this code from some other developer and dont know smarty that well so sorry for the lack of details.

Comment: there is lot of opening and closing bracket error in your code

Comment: `smarty_block_m3_validate_box` is unknown to me, that must be some kind of custom function. What does it contain?

Comment: probably part of the smarty templating engine.

Comment: I think its because some arguments are used as reference in the function, so you cant pass function call directly. for example array_pop. Try to put the returned value of array_pop in a variable then pass the variable in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part of your code:

```
<?php
smarty_block_m3_validate_box($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $this->_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat=false);
```

You created `smarty_block_m3_validate_box` with:

```
<?php
function smarty_block_m3_validate_box($params, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat)
```

(Parameter 3 and 4 are passed by reference)

Now you're trying to pass `$_block_repeat=false` as the third parameter, which will work, but throws an E_STRICT error (like you get). The solution would be to assign `$_block_repeat` with the value you want and pass it to the function:

```
<?php
$_block_repeat = false;
smarty_block_m3_validate_box($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $this->_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Yeah same error message. It appears when trying to save/edit a lot of things in the backend of the site.